# Comparing non-deterministic and also the deterministic expressive power of FA, PDA's and TM'S

Tags: turing-machines, finite-automata, computation-models, pushdown-automata, nondeterminism

I am sorta confused and also could not find a answer online, but in terms of expressive power, .

Non-deterministic FA, PDA, TM

```
NFA < NPDA < NTM
```

Deterministic FA,PDA,TM: This is where i am confused

```
DFA < PDA < TM?
```

In a whole: ?

```
DFA = NFA = e-NFA = RE < DPDA < NPDA = NCFL = DCFL < NTM = DTM?
```

Please correct me or am i correct?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47805153/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was cross-posted on SO.